# cli mounted not working the second time via router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I created a vue.js router like this:

```
  {
    path: '/hello/:type',
    name: 'hello',
    component: HelloView,
  },
```

in the component "HelloView" i put this mounted:

```
mounted() {
   alert("test")
},
```

the first time i go to: http://localhost:8080/hello/whatever everything was ok and i get the alert message.
next time i go to other link: http://localhost:8080/hello/whatever2 (via `<router-link>`) i didn't get the alert message.
how can I make mounted run in the second time?

Comment: as far as I know, `mounted` is called only once during the component life-cycle.

Comment: So what's the alternative? How can i cause the alert message to run on routeing change

Comment: if i were you, I would use `watchers` and passing property and watching property's value change and alert the message.

Comment: there are multiple ways, you can also define a method and call it via `ref` (this.$refs...)

Comment: `mounted` will only run when your component gets mounted. Changing routes does not trigger the `mounted`. You can `watch` `$route` or you can use router method like `beforeEnter` or `beforeEach`